# <Select multiple> not working on html form with php

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, post

Okay, so I have a html form, and a using php for the server side validation to send the information from the form as an email. I cannot, for the life of me, get the form to send the  items as an array.

Here's my html:

```
   <select multiple name="symptoms[]">
   <option value="ADHD">ADHD</option>
   <option value="Insomnia">Insomnia</option>
   <option value="Depression">Depression</option>
   <option value="PTSD">PTSD</option>
   <option value="Autism">Autism</option>
   <option value="Stress">Stress</option>
   <option value="Addiction">Addiction</option>
   <option value="Pain">Pain/Headaches</option>
```

Here's my php in which I think the problem lies:

```
// validation expected data exists

if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['email']) ||

    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

    !isset($_POST['symptoms']) ||

    !isset($_POST['location']) ||

    !isset($_POST['comment'])) {

    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

}

$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

$symptoms = $_POST['symptoms']; // not required

$location = $_POST['location']; // not required

$comments = $_POST['comment']; // required
```

There is also this section of php, but I don't think the 'symptoms' area is a problem here...

```
function clean_string($string) {

  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

$email_message .= "Symptoms: ".clean_string($symptoms)."\n";

$email_message .= "Location: ".clean_string($location)."\n";

$email_message .= "Comment: ".clean_string($location)."\n";
```

I have been trying to change the !isset all day and the $symptoms lines to get the 'symptoms' select multiple to show up on my email as an array. Right now it just says "array" in the email. I was thinking maybe the .clean-string should be something to do with array instead of string? I'm completely stuck, I've tried everything I can find, copied and pasted and tinkered and changed about 5 different sets of codes I found on stackoverflow...

Comment: `died()` does not exist. I'm assuming you mean `die()`;

Comment: That's also kind of a funny `clean_string()` function. What are you trying to prevent with that?

Comment: Yes, Mike, I screwed that up, thank you. To be honest I was having some issues with the strings (probably related to something I missed while working, php is not my strength, I usually just do front end) and found that code. Everything but the array worked when I was done so I just figured it helped. Thank you!

Comment: When you are copying and pasting code you should at least understand what it does. If you copy a function and then apply it to a list of variables, it would be good to at least understand what it does. If it is supposed to "clean" the variable, figure out *what* exactly it is trying to clean from the variable and *why*. It looks to me like you are sending a plain text email, so I really don't know of any way someone could inject something malicious into a plain text email. HTML would be a different story, but there are PHP functions for that. More than likely you can get rid of `clean_string`.

Answer (score 1):

If you `echo` (or concatenate, or some other method which will cast to string) an array, it will just say "Array", so you have to convert it to a string somehow. One method is to use `implode`, so you can display the array as a comma separated list:

```
$email_message .= "Symptoms: ".clean_string(implode(", ",$symptoms))."\n";
```

http://php.net/implode

if you want to get fancy and make sure there is an " and" before the last item, you could do

```
$symptomString = implode(", ", $symptoms); 
$lastComma = strrpos($symptomString, ", ");
$symptomString = substr_replace($symptomString, "and", $lastComma, 2);
```

Comment: ChiliNUT holy crap that was the bit of code I thought was correct and was looking elsewhere. I was trying to change the !isset. Like I said in my comment to Mike, php (well, to be honest, most backend) is not my strength at all. Thank you so much for your help, everything seems to be in order now.

Comment: @Phil yeah that threw me when I first started with php, javascript will happily convert an array to a comma separated string for you if you print one.